# How do I drop a column for a MySQL view programatically?

Tags: mysql, view, alter

I'd like to alter views in mysql and drop columns. I've got to do this for lots of views so I'd like to script it.

If the views were tables, I could use ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN blah but I don't think I can use this sytax on views.

Can I remove columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to do this? (Seems V. Risky!)

Is there some nice syntax I'm missing or do I have to parse the ALTER VIEW statement I can get from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS and regenerate the view? (Not nice either)

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Aren't the columns a view returns defined by the SELECT statement within the view?  As such, you'd have to update the actual query within the view, using a CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW command.

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove a column from a view. You must instead [alter the definition of the view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-view.html).

All tables in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database are actually views to ease access to the information they contain. It is not possible to alter them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALTER VIEW statement and just not adding the column you are looking for to dropping; you cannot drop a column in a view.

You can get a full detail here:

[alter view statement](https://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/views.shtml)

A small example could be:

You have Animal table with columns id, name, color and owner.

Then you want to show Animal.name, Animal.color and Animal.owner

Then,

```
CREATE VIEW AnimalView AS SELECT Animal.name AS 'animalName', Animal.color AS 'animalColor', Animal.owner as 'animalOwner' FROM Animal;
```

Then, if you want to drop the column owner, just alter the view:

```
ALTER VIEW AnimalView AS SELECT Animal.name AS 'animalName', Animal.color AS 'animalColor' FROM Animal;
```

The script should work with that. You can't drop a column.